# Can't bind SelectItem list to <f:selectItem

Tags: jsf, icefaces, selectonemenu

I am using IceFaces components and I am trying to fill up a select with some values that correspond to a MangedBean property.

```
<h:form>
    <ice:selectOneMenu size="1" style="width: 180px">
        <f:selectItem value="#{stockManagedBean.listeCategoriesItem}"></f:selectItem>
    </ice:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

listeCategoriesItem is a property of StockManagedBean and is an ArrayList of SelectItem.

```
@ManagedBean
public class StockManagedBean {
    CategorieDAO categorieDAO;
    List<SelectItem> listeCategoriesItem;

    public StockManagedBean() {
        categorieDAO = new CategorieDAO();
        listeCategoriesItem = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();    
        List<Categorie> listeCategories = categorieDAO.selectAllCat();
        for(Categorie categorie: listeCategories) {
            listeCategoriesItem.add(new SelectItem(categorie.getCatId(), categorie.getCatNom()));
        }
    }

public List<SelectItem> getListeCategoriesItem() {
    return listeCategoriesItem; 
}

public void setListeCategoriesItem(List<SelectItem> listeCategoriesItem) {
    this.listeCategoriesItem = listeCategoriesItem;
}
}
```

I tested the values that come from my DAO and they are all correct. I also tested the values of the list in the getter and they are also correct, but when I load my html page, nothing is in the select list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<f:selectItems>` instead of `<f:selectItem>`. Note the **s** at the end of the former component.

```
<ice:selectOneMenu size="1" style="width: 180px">
    <f:selectItems value="#{stockManagedBean.listeCategoriesItem}" />
</ice:selectOneMenu>
```

Also, it would be good to also have a field in your bean that will handle the value of the selected item in your `selectOneMenu`.

```
<ice:selectOneMenu size="1" style="width: 180px"
    value="#{stockManagedBean.selectedCategory}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{stockManagedBean.listeCategoriesItem}" />
</ice:selectOneMenu>
```

And in your managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class StockManagedBean {
    private String selectedCategory;
    //rest of your code
    //getters and setters...
}
```

Comment: I lost so many time searching for the solution, what a stupid error haha. And good tip, thank you!

Comment: Also, remember to use correct case though not related to your question, I had trouble using normal case vs camelCase tags!